# Python/Pygame Making An Object Follow Another Object

Tags: python, programming-languages, pygame

I Have Been Trying for days on how to do this. Basically You Control A Player, And zombies follow you.
Problem Is, I Cant Seem To Get The Zombies To Follow! I Tried If Statements For Example

```
    if playerx > zombiex:
        zombiex=zombiex - 2
        screen.blit(zombie,(zombiex,zombiey))
```

aaaaaand That Didnt Work.... :/
Any Ideas?

Comment: That code snippet isn't enough to show what the problem may be.  Why not write out in some pseudo-code what your algorithm would look like and see where your logic is flawed.

Comment: If `playerx` was GREATER than `zombiex` you made `zombiex` SMALLER?

Comment: it was just an example i didnt really use this code. i just THOUGHT of doing something like this. and i was in a hurry thats why there are flaws on this code snip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you searched for.

```
def length(x, y):
    return (x ** 2 + y ** 2) ** .5

def norm(x, y):
    _len    = length(x, y)
    return x / _len, y / _len

class ZombieController(object):

    def __init__(self, zombie_view_range):
        self._zombs = []
        self.append = self._zombs.append
        self._range = zombie_view_range

    def NextFrame(self, player_pos):
        px, py      = player_pos
        _range      = self._range
        for zombie in self._zombs:
            x, y    = zombie.position
            dx, dy  = px - x, py - y
            _len    = length(dx, dy)
            if _len <= _range:
                speed       = zombie.speed
                direction   = norm(dx, dy)
                zombie.positon  = x + direction[0] * speed, y + direction[1] * speed
```

Answer (score 0):

First, can't answer your whole questions as there's not enough information. How doesn't it work exactly?

Second, if you want the zombies to follow, you need thier coordinates to converge with the players so you need something like:

```
if playerx > zombiex:
    zombiex = zombiex + max(zombiespeed, playerx - zombiex)
elif playerx < zombiex:
    zombiex = zombiex - max(zombiespeed, zombiex - playerx)
```

NB:

- I replace `2` with `zombiespeed` which you define elsewhere so you can change the speed in one place for future.
- I use `max()` to ensure the zombie won't move PAST the player when very close.
- You'd obviously do the same for the `y` direction too.